# JPA: Delete the content of multiple entities on cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, derby

Since some days ago I cannot find a solution to the following problem:

My application contains the entities:

```
- Wording
- Language
- Category
- Example
```

With the following relationships:

```
Wording 1 ------->------- 1 Language

Wording 1 ------->------- 1 Category

Category 1 ------>--------1 Language

Wording 1 ------->--------* Example
```

My target is to delete a ***Language*** and consequently the rest of entities get deleted on cascade.
For example, if I delete the *language* "English", all *categories* and *wordings* should be deleted, and also the *examples* linked to the *wordings*.

This **works** when I do the SQL schema, manually, on my Derby database (in memory), only setting "ON DELETE CASCADE" on all foreign keys. Then I run:

```
DELETE FROM Language WHERE name = 'English';
```

But something I am doing wrong when I configure my @Entities, because it returns issues concerning the Examples.
If the Wording contains no examples, then the deletion works as a charm, otherwise I receive the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

More info:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Wording")
public class Wording implements Serializable {
(...)
    private long wordingId;
    private Language language;
    private Category category;
    private Set <Example> examples = new HashSet<>(); 
(...)

    @Id
    @Column(name = "wordingId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getWordingId() {
        return wordingId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "languageId", nullable = false)
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", nullable = false)    
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)    
    @JoinColumn(name = "wordingId")
    public Set<Example> getExamples() {
        return examples;
    }
(...)
```

Therefore my question is: Why this configuration does not reproduce the same SQL schema, that I did before, manually, and works?

Thanks! ;-)

EDIT:

Below part of the stack:
(It arises when deleting all languages)

> 2017-10-10 17:56:52.421 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        : select
>   examples0_.wording_id as wording_6_1_0_, examples0_.example_id as
>   example_1_1_0_, examples0_.example_id as example_1_1_1_,
>   examples0_.created_on as created_2_1_1_, examples0_.enable as
>   enable3_1_1_, examples0_.example as example4_1_1_,
>   examples0_.modified_on as modified5_1_1_ from example examples0_ where
>   examples0_.wording_id=? Hibernate: select examples0_.wording_id as
>   wording_6_1_0_, examples0_.example_id as example_1_1_0_,
>   examples0_.example_id as example_1_1_1_, examples0_.created_on as
>   created_2_1_1_, examples0_.enable as enable3_1_1_, examples0_.example
>   as example4_1_1_, examples0_.modified_on as modified5_1_1_ from
>   example examples0_ where examples0_.wording_id=? 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.427 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
>   [BIGINT] - [1] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.444 DEBUG 6120 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select
>   language0_.language_id as language1_2_, language0_.created_on as
>   created_2_2_, language0_.enable as enable3_2_, language0_.flag as
>   flag4_2_, language0_.language as language5_2_, language0_.modified_on
>   as modified6_2_ from languagge language0_ Hibernate: select
>   language0_.language_id as language1_2_, language0_.created_on as
>   created_2_2_, language0_.enable as enable3_2_, language0_.flag as
>   flag4_2_, language0_.language as language5_2_, language0_.modified_on
>   as modified6_2_ from languagge language0_ 2017-10-10 17:56:52.456
>   DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : delete from languagge where language_id=? Hibernate: delete from
>   languagge where language_id=? 2017-10-10 17:56:52.473 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1]
>   as [BIGINT] - [1] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.505 DEBUG 6120 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into languagge
>   (language_id, created_on, enable, flag, language, modified_on) values
>   (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into languagge
>   (language_id, created_on, enable, flag, language, modified_on) values
>   (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-10-10 17:56:52.505 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.506 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as
>   [SMALLINT] - [true] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.506 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3]
>   as [VARBINARY] - [null] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.506 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4]
>   as [VARCHAR] - [English] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.506 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.507 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : values identity_val_local() Hibernate: values identity_val_local()
>   2017-10-10 17:56:52.509 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into category
>   (category_id, category, created_on, enable, language_id, modified_on)
>   values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into category
>   (category_id, category, created_on, enable, language_id, modified_on)
>   values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-10-10 17:56:52.510 TRACE 6120 ---
>   [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
>   parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [myCategory] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.510
>   TRACE 6120 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
>   : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST
>   2017] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.510 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as
>   [SMALLINT] - [true] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.511 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4]
>   as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.511 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.511 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : values identity_val_local() Hibernate: values identity_val_local()
>   2017-10-10 17:56:52.551 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into wording
>   (wording_id, category_id, created_on, image, language_id, modified_on,
>   wording) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into
>   wording (wording_id, category_id, created_on, image, language_id,
>   modified_on, wording) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.552 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
>   [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.552 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.552 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as
>   [BLOB] - [[B@1769d] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.552 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4]
>   as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.553 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.553 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as
>   [VARCHAR] - [MyWording] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.554 DEBUG 6120 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : values
>   identity_val_local() Hibernate: values identity_val_local() 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.555 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : insert into example (example_id, created_on, enable, example,
>   modified_on) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into
>   example (example_id, created_on, enable, example, modified_on) values
>   (default, ?, ?, ?, ?) 2017-10-10 17:56:52.559 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.559 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as
>   [SMALLINT] - [true] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.559 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3]
>   as [VARCHAR] - [myExample] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.560 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4]
>   as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.561 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : values identity_val_local() Hibernate: values identity_val_local()
>   2017-10-10 17:56:52.562 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into example
>   (example_id, created_on, enable, example, modified_on) values
>   (default, ?, ?, ?, ?) Hibernate: insert into example (example_id,
>   created_on, enable, example, modified_on) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   2017-10-10 17:56:52.562 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as
>   [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.562
>   TRACE 6120 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
>   : binding parameter [2] as [SMALLINT] - [true] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.563
>   TRACE 6120 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
>   : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [myAnotherExample] 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.563 TRACE 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as
>   [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Oct 10 17:56:52 CEST 2017] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.564
>   DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : values identity_val_local() Hibernate: values identity_val_local()
>   2017-10-10 17:56:52.566 DEBUG 6120 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.SQL                        : update example set
>   wording_id=? where example_id=? Hibernate: update example set
>   wording_id=? where example_id=? 2017-10-10 17:56:52.572 TRACE 6120 ---
>   [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
>   parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.573 TRACE 6120 ---
>   [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
>   parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.575 DEBUG 6120 ---
>   [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update
>   example set wording_id=? where example_id=? Hibernate: update example
>   set wording_id=? where example_id=? 2017-10-10 17:56:52.576 TRACE 6120
>   --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.576 TRACE
>   6120 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      :
>   binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.592 DEBUG
>   6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        :
>   select wording0_.wording_id as wording_1_4_0_, wording0_.category_id
>   as category6_4_0_, wording0_.created_on as created_2_4_0_,
>   wording0_.image as image3_4_0_, wording0_.language_id as
>   language7_4_0_, wording0_.modified_on as modified4_4_0_,
>   wording0_.wording as wording5_4_0_, category1_.category_id as
>   category1_0_1_, category1_.category as category2_0_1_,
>   category1_.created_on as created_3_0_1_, category1_.enable as
>   enable4_0_1_, category1_.language_id as language6_0_1_,
>   category1_.modified_on as modified5_0_1_, language2_.language_id as
>   language1_2_2_, language2_.created_on as created_2_2_2_,
>   language2_.enable as enable3_2_2_, language2_.flag as flag4_2_2_,
>   language2_.language as language5_2_2_, language2_.modified_on as
>   modified6_2_2_, examples3_.wording_id as wording_6_1_3_,
>   examples3_.example_id as example_1_1_3_, examples3_.example_id as
>   example_1_1_4_, examples3_.created_on as created_2_1_4_,
>   examples3_.enable as enable3_1_4_, examples3_.example as
>   example4_1_4_, examples3_.modified_on as modified5_1_4_,
>   language4_.language_id as language1_2_5_, language4_.created_on as
>   created_2_2_5_, language4_.enable as enable3_2_5_, language4_.flag as
>   flag4_2_5_, language4_.language as language5_2_5_,
>   language4_.modified_on as modified6_2_5_ from wording wording0_ inner
>   join category category1_ on
>   wording0_.category_id=category1_.category_id inner join languagge
>   language2_ on category1_.language_id=language2_.language_id left outer
>   join example examples3_ on wording0_.wording_id=examples3_.wording_id
>   left outer join languagge language4_ on
>   wording0_.language_id=language4_.language_id where
>   wording0_.wording_id=? Hibernate: select wording0_.wording_id as
>   wording_1_4_0_, wording0_.category_id as category6_4_0_,
>   wording0_.created_on as created_2_4_0_, wording0_.image as
>   image3_4_0_, wording0_.language_id as language7_4_0_,
>   wording0_.modified_on as modified4_4_0_, wording0_.wording as
>   wording5_4_0_, category1_.category_id as category1_0_1_,
>   category1_.category as category2_0_1_, category1_.created_on as
>   created_3_0_1_, category1_.enable as enable4_0_1_,
>   category1_.language_id as language6_0_1_, category1_.modified_on as
>   modified5_0_1_, language2_.language_id as language1_2_2_,
>   language2_.created_on as created_2_2_2_, language2_.enable as
>   enable3_2_2_, language2_.flag as flag4_2_2_, language2_.language as
>   language5_2_2_, language2_.modified_on as modified6_2_2_,
>   examples3_.wording_id as wording_6_1_3_, examples3_.example_id as
>   example_1_1_3_, examples3_.example_id as example_1_1_4_,
>   examples3_.created_on as created_2_1_4_, examples3_.enable as
>   enable3_1_4_, examples3_.example as example4_1_4_,
>   examples3_.modified_on as modified5_1_4_, language4_.language_id as
>   language1_2_5_, language4_.created_on as created_2_2_5_,
>   language4_.enable as enable3_2_5_, language4_.flag as flag4_2_5_,
>   language4_.language as language5_2_5_, language4_.modified_on as
>   modified6_2_5_ from wording wording0_ inner join category category1_
>   on wording0_.category_id=category1_.category_id inner join languagge
>   language2_ on category1_.language_id=language2_.language_id left outer
>   join example examples3_ on wording0_.wording_id=examples3_.wording_id
>   left outer join languagge language4_ on
>   wording0_.language_id=language4_.language_id where
>   wording0_.wording_id=? 2017-10-10 17:56:52.604 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1]
>   as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.633 DEBUG 6120 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select
>   language0_.language_id as language1_2_, language0_.created_on as
>   created_2_2_, language0_.enable as enable3_2_, language0_.flag as
>   flag4_2_, language0_.language as language5_2_, language0_.modified_on
>   as modified6_2_ from languagge language0_ Hibernate: select
>   language0_.language_id as language1_2_, language0_.created_on as
>   created_2_2_, language0_.enable as enable3_2_, language0_.flag as
>   flag4_2_, language0_.language as language5_2_, language0_.modified_on
>   as modified6_2_ from languagge language0_ 2017-10-10 17:56:52.634
>   DEBUG 6120 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL
>   : delete from languagge where language_id=? Hibernate: delete from
>   languagge where language_id=? 2017-10-10 17:56:52.634 TRACE 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1]
>   as [BIGINT] - [2] 2017-10-10 17:56:52.649  WARN 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 20000,
>   SQLState: 23503 2017-10-10 17:56:52.650 ERROR 6120 --- [
>   main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DELETE on table
>   'WORDING' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK_WORDING'
>   for key (2).  The statement has been rolled back. 2017-10-10
>   17:56:52.651  INFO 6120 --- [           main]
>   o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of
>   batch it still contained JDBC statements Tests run: 4, Failures: 0,
>   Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 9.076 sec <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.mycompany.languages.model.dao.WordingDAOTest
>   testDeleteAfterDeletingLanguage(com.mycompany.languages.model.dao.WordingDAOTest)
>   Time elapsed: 0.06 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ReferencedKeyRIChecker.doCheck(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RISetChecker.doPKCheck(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.DeleteResultSet.runFkChecker(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.DeleteCascadeResultSet.runFkChecker(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.DeleteCascadeResultSet.runFkChecker(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.DeleteCascadeResultSet.runFkChecker(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.DeleteCascadeResultSet.open(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3498)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:98)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.deleteAll(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.mycompany.languages.model.dao.WordingDAOTest.setUp(WordingDAOTest.java:222)
>
> 2017-10-10 17:56:52.694  INFO 6120 --- [       Thread-4]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@865dd6:
>   startup date [Tue Oct 10 17:56:44 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy 2017-10-10 17:56:52.698  INFO 6120 --- [       Thread-4]
>   j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Results :

Tests in error: 
  WordingDAOTest.setUp:222 » DataIntegrityViolation could not execute statement;...

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because you're trying to delete some `languages` that are used in `Wording` and `Wording`  don't accept that `language` can be `null` so try to use that instead :

```
 @ManyToOne
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "languageId", nullable = true)
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not solve the issue. The problem arises when there are wordings with available examples. Without them, it always worked!

Comment: Can you post all the stack that you get ?